# Django-q with Amazon SQS configuration

Tags: django, amazon-sqs, django-q

I've been trying to configure Django-q for the first time, with Amazon SQS as a broker.

I'm using Python 2.7.11, Django 1.11.5, Django-q 0.9.2, boto3 1.5.28 and django-storages 1.4.1.

I've been already using AWS S3 and cloudfront in my Django app for a few years, so they are configured properly. I'm using S3 and cloudfront for serving media files, while django-whitenoise for serving django static files.

I've created new IAM user just for SQS and gave it `AmazonSQSFullAccess`. 
List of apps im using in my project (`settings.py`):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'utils',
    'storages',
    'my_app',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_q',
)
```

Following the [Django-q documentation](http://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), I've come up to the step where I should execute this command:

```
python manage.py qcluster
```

Which gives me these errors:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'boto3.resources.factory.sqs.ServiceResource'> it's not found as boto3.resources.factory.sqs.ServiceResource
```

and Django error as well:

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady(aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Which leaves me confused, I really have no idea what could be the problem..

**UPDATE**

This is cmd full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django_q\management\commands\qcluster.py", line 22, in handle
    q.start()
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django_q\cluster.py", line 54, in start
    self.sentinel.start()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
  self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
  dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
  ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
  self.save(obj)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
  save(state)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
  self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
  save(v)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
  save(element)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
  save(state)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
  self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
  save(v)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
  save(cls)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
  (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'boto3.resources.factory.sqs.ServiceRe
source'>: it's not found as boto3.resources.factory.sqs.ServiceResource

(my_app) just_a_path_to_my_app\fakultet>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
  self = load(from_parent)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
  return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
  dispatch[key](self)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
  klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
  __import__(module)
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django_q\cluster.py", line 25, in <module>
    import tasks
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django_q\tasks.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cluster
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django_q\cluster.py", line 29, in <module>
    from django_q.models import Task, Success, Schedule
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django_q\models.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Task(models.Model):
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "just_a_path_to_my_app\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace from the error(s)?

Comment: @markwalker_ I have updated my question with error(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware of the fact that django-q has [Windows compatibility issues](https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/issues/50), so that was the reason why i wasn't able to make it to work under my Windows development machine. After i installed django-q on my production CentOS server and followed simple configuration instructions - everything went well.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found the solution. you should mark your answer as correct, so this question would leave the list of unanswered questions